# Define SmallInt constant as hexadecimal

Tags: delphi, casting

I need to define a `SmallInt` constant with a hexadecimal value. In some way like this:

```
const
  a: SmallInt = $8000;
```

Of course, the `$8000` value violates subrange bounds of `SmallInt`. I know it and do it deliberately.
Actually, I need a bitwise transfer of this literal to 16-bit signed integer.

If it were a variable, I could use an `absolute` keyword:

```
var
  a_prototype: Word;
  a: SmallInt absolute a_prototype;
begin
  a_prototype := $8000;
```

but it should be a constant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a cast

```
const
  a = SmallInt($8000);
```

If you need a typed constant then it would be

```
const
  a: SmallInt = SmallInt($8000);
```